# What is the difference between database.rules.json and firestore.rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I recently started to use firebase.

As the title says, I would like to know the difference of the files between "database.rules.json" and "firestore.rules".
Since the both of them have the similar content about database rule, it is hard for me to figure out why there are two separate files. Do I need the both files and should I use the either file and also if not what is the role of each one?

I looked up and tried to find the answer but could not reach it, so decided to ask here.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

database.rules.json is for [Realtime Database security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security).

firestore.rules is for [Firestore security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).

They are different database products with different rule systems.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason I have the two files in my project directory is I selected both Realtime Database and Firestore when I ran `firebase init`.